# mongodb Pipeline option is not working in my spark scala code

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, etl, pipeline

I am trying to build ETL pipeline from Mongodb to redshift. so i am trying to read data from mongodb collection where one column updated_at should greater than let suppose yesterday. so because of this i am using pipeline option in spark scala code.
using below code count (df.count();) is of records is same as without pipeline option

//i am trying below code.

```
val pipeline = """[
  {
    $match:
      {
        updated_at: {
          $gte: ISODate(
            "2022-03-07T03:39:19.416+00:00"
          )
        }
      }
  }
]"""

val df = spark.read.format("mongodb").
    option("connection.uri", connectionUri).
    option("database", database).
    option("collection", collection).
    option("pipeline", pipeline).
    load()
```

Comment: `ISODate()` is a function in the `mongosh`. I have no clue about spark, but I would guess you have to use the [date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#date) function instead. Or you can try [$dateFromString](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) or simply `{ $expr: {$gte: ["$updated_at", { $dateSubtract: { startDate: "$$NOW", unit: 1, amount: "day" } }]}}`

Comment: ISODATE() is working in mongo compass in aggregation. that's why i am using it. any way it's not working